# Replicate GEE from SPSS in R - differences in output

Tags: r, spss, generalized-estimating-equations

I am trying to replicate the results from a GEE I have done with SPSS in R.

The dataset I am using can be found [here](https://github.com/MSmit1992/Effect-environment-cat-behaviour/blob/main/Data.csv)

**SPSS Script**

```
GENLIN Lying BY Week Day (ORDER=DESCENDING) WITH Temperature Humidity Wind_Speed C_Rain
/MODEL Week Day Temperature Humidity Wind_Speed C_Rain Week*Day INTERCEPT=YES
DISTRIBUTION=POISSON LINK=LOG
/CRITERIA METHOD=FISHER(1) SCALE=1 MAXITERATIONS=100 MAXSTEPHALVING=5 PCONVERGE=1E- 
006(ABSOLUTE) 
SINGULAR=1E-012 ANALYSISTYPE=3(WALD) CILEVEL=95 LIKELIHOOD=FULL
/REPEATED SUBJECT=Cat_id WITHINSUBJECT=Week*Day*hour SORT=YES CORRTYPE=AR(1) ADJUSTCORR=YES 
COVB=ROBUST MAXITERATIONS=100 PCONVERGE=1e-006(ABSOLUTE) UPDATECORR=1
/MISSING CLASSMISSING=EXCLUDE
/PRINT CPS DESCRIPTIVES MODELINFO FIT SUMMARY SOLUTION.
```

**R-Code**

```
library(geepack)
df <- read.csv("https://github.com/MSmit1992/Effect-environment-cat- 
behaviour/blob/main/Data.csv")
gee1 <- geeglm(Lying ~ Week + Day + Temperature + Humidity + Wind_Speed + C_Rain + Week*Day, 
data=df, family="poisson", id=Cat_id, corstr="ar1")
anova(gee1)
summary(gee1)
```

**Problem 1: Differences in results between SPSS & R**

When comparing the output of SPSS and R, there are quite some differences in the results, both in the `anova` tables (SPSS: Tests of Model Effects) and the Parameter Estimates.

[image]

One of the possible reasons for the differences in output, is that there might be an error in the R-code/`geeglm` function. I am not sure how to account for the multiple repeated measures I have (week, day, hour) in the `geeglm` function. This is easier in SPSS.

Another possible reason I was thinking of, is the way the dataset is ordered. Which leads me to the second problem.

**Problem 2: `geeglm` function not finishing when ordering dataset**

One of the things with the `geeglm`, according to the [user guide](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geepack/vignettes/geepack-manual.pdf), is that the data should be ordered according to id and then the repeated measures. In the dataset used in both SPSS and R above, the dataset is ordered according to Week > Cat_id. According to the user guide, this gives some wrong results. However, when I reorder the dataset to Cat_id > Week and run the `geeglm` function, it just keeps on running without ever showing results. I have tried to reorder the dataset two ways:

```
df <- df[order(df$Cat_id,df$Week),]
# or
wav <- df$Week
```

The function just keeps on running without an end in both cases, to the point I have to forcefully stop R and have to restart R. I thought that maybe this is part of the reason for the differences in the results found between the SPSS and R output, but I do not know how to solve this problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

*ps. I wasn't quite sure whether the best place to post this was Cross Validated or Stack Overflow, so I do apologize if it fits better at Stack Overflow*